Cannot query Enum with Spring JPA and Postgresql
So i have this ENUM in my PostgreSQL:
CREATE TYPE process_status AS ENUM('CREATED','ONGOING','DONE');

ALTER TABLE process ADD status process_status NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CREATED';

In my code:
@Getter
public enum Status {
    CREATED("Created"),
    ONGOING("Ongoing"),
    DONE("Done");

    private final String status;

    Status(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

In my Process class i use the enum:
public class Process extends RepresentationModel<Process> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status = Status.CREATED;
}

In my repository:
public interface ProcessRepository extends JpaRepository<Process, UUID> {
    List<Process> findByIdNotAndStatusNot(UUID id, Status status);
}

In my service i call the Repository
processList = processRepository.findByIdNotAndStatusNot(id, Status.DONE);
And i get this error:
ERROR: operator does not exist: process_status <> character varying

Does anyone have an idea of what am i doing wrong?

My solution was to add the @ColumnTransformer annotation to cast the types:


It's because there is no automatic cast between varchar and your type, you can check PostgreSQLEnumType from hypersistence-utils or implement your own. Otherwise you can also create an automatic cast in the DB side https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html.
